# How to fix codemirror not loaded correct?

Tags: eclipse, codemirror

I am using codemirror and sometime when I run my project the codemirror not loadedd fine and not allow to me to write on it .... [image: this picture to codemirror appare wrong]

in picture above I color yellow number codemirror display (I did not knew why display this numbers and why did not allow to me to write on it )

the first time the problem appare I solved it by call (editor.refresh();)
But now the call of (editor.refresh();) not solved my problem ...  I did not knew if the problem from codemirror or from tomac server or from eclipse ...please any help ?

Comment: Any body can help